# Importing using string in Python

Tags: python

Short version:

Say I have a string `str` and a file `functions.py` from which I would like to import a method whose name is stored in `str`.

How do I go about it? I would like something like:

```
from functions.py import str
```

but have str evaluated and not to import the method 'str' (which doesn't exist).

After some googling I came as close (I hope) as:

```
func_name = str
_tmp = __import__('functions.py', globals(), locals(), ['func_name'], -1)
func = ???? <what to put here?>
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: TMI.

Comment: Note you should import `functions` and not `functions.py`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your code to import the module into `_tmp` works then the final step is simply:

```
func = getattr(_tmp, func_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `getattr` method gives you an attribute of a given object. Since global functions are attributes of the module they are in, you can use this:

```
import functions

funcName = 'doSomething'
f = getattr(functions, funcName)
f(123)
```

There is no need to use `__import__`, as that's usually needed only when you don't know the module name in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to save memory by only importing the functions you need, don't bother; even if you used the `from ... import ...` construct, Python still imports the whole module, just that it only adds to the current dictionary those members that you explicitly requested (the others are still in memory, just that they're not accessible directly).

With that in mind, I would do something along these lines:

```
import functions
the_name = self.name.lower() + str(i)
the_func = getattr(functions, the_name)
```

Comment: TypeError: 'module' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @Mark Ah, right. You forget the little bits after not using the language for some time. :)